# GestureRecogniser not working when going back

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, swipe, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using `SWRevealController` class to add a sidebar. This adds a gesture recogniser for a swipe.

I have a table with a few choices and initially the swipe works fine. However, if I select a choice, go to the new page and then come back via the nav, the swipe STOPS working (however the button for the sidebar still works).

This is the code for the swipe added to `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: What else do you do with the gesture?

Comment: Nothing else, it's just a swipe from the left

Comment: Literally following this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

Comment: Are you adding it to the other view?

Comment: Yes, it's just when I use the navbar to go back. If I load the sidebar via the button and then go to the initial page then it all works fine again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];` in `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad` so that it is replaced following each transition. A gesture can only be attached to one view at a time so when you attach it to a different view it gets removed from the first.

Alternatively, consider adding the gesture to a more root view (like the window / navigation bar) depending on what interaction you want to enable.

Comment: I tried this - it doesn't even work at all when I put it into viewWillAppear :/ The gesture isn't even detected :/ Do I need to do something to the tableview?

Comment: Then you have some other issue. Are you using any other gestures?

Comment: Erm nothing - There's just a scroll on my table and that's it. It's literally a table where clicking a cell goes to a new view and then when I come back via NAVIGATION it stops working. If I come back via the sidebar then it's fine :s Maybe it's the segues :/

Comment: When you come back, log the gestures connected to the view

Comment: How do I do that? (sorry I'm new with this :/)

Comment: You know how to log? `self.view.gestureRecognizers`

Comment: Where should I add this? viewDidLoad? Whilst keeping the old line?

Comment: yes, and viewWillAppear:, and viewDidAppear: (and be sure you can tell which log is which when they are printed)

Comment: I'm a bit confused sorry, can you explain it again? :(

Comment: Ah it's working! I cleared cache and reset and for some reason it started working when I added it to viewWillAppear again! Thanks!